# Unable to upload Images in Python

Tags: python, django, django-admin

**models**

```
image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/shows",blank=True,null=True)
```

I need to upload the image at a particular directory. I am trying to add these media files using admin panel. How do I upload the images ?

**Edit 1**

```
http://192.168.2.9:8000/static/uploads/shows/myImage.jpg

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.2.9:8000/static/uploads/shows/myImage.jpg
'uploads/shows/myImage.jpg' could not be found
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**Edit 2**

```
    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = ''

    # URL prefix for static files.
    # Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: you need to set the [STATIC settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error does not say your upload failed ; it's saying it failed to find the file once uploaded. So like the doc explains about "[Serving uploaded content](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user)", you also need to set MEDIA settings like they suggest to us.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and then [you will be able to upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/file-uploads/) your file too